# Solved! How to connect javascript files in Rails application?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am writing a simple Ruby on Rails training application, and use *semantic-ui* css framework. 
From dropdown menu need to write a little code for jquery. 
If I write **.js** code directly in **html** code, it works. 
If I put it in a separate file **app/assets/javascripts/dropdown.js** this code stop working. But! If use **.coffee**, the code works again!
How to connect **js** files to Rails?

So, i have **javascript/dropdown.js**. I tried to include it in a **application.js** file, although this is not necessary, it did not work.
I write this code directly in **application.js** - not work

---

#### Solution:

I made a syntax error. I mixed up the closing brackets in method `$(document).ready`. The **.coffee** file worked, because there are no brackets! Do not code at night, the brain does not work well. I found my mistake in the morning.
**P.S.** as a result i used `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){})` in **dropdown.js**. If use **'turbolinks:load'**, dropdown menu will work on all pages of the site, and not just on the index page.

---

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require semantic-ui
//= require rails-ujs
//= require dropdown
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**dropdown.js**

```
$('.dropdown').dropdown({transition: 'drop'});
```

**dropdown.js** not work too

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').dropdown({transition: 'drop'});
})
```

**_header.html.erb**

```
_header.html.erb

<div class="ui secondary menu">
  <div class="ui container">
    <%= link_to "Sample App", root_path, id: "logo", class: "item header" %>
    <div class="right menu">
      <%= link_to "Home",   root_path, class: "item" %>
      <%= link_to "Help",   help_path, class: "item" %>
      <% if logged_in? %>
        <%= link_to "Users", '#', class: "item" %>
        <div class="ui dropdown item">
        Account <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="menu">
          <%= link_to "Profile", current_user, class: "item" %>
          <%= link_to "Settings", '#', class: "item" %>
          <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete", class: "item" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Log in", login_path, class: "item" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  // Script from dropdown: assets/javascript/dropdown.js
  //$('.dropdown').dropdown({transition: 'drop'});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get any console errors? Try putting a `console.log` statement inside the callback for `$(document).ready`. Does the message log successfully?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. The `alert ()` call works both in the **application.js** file and in the **dropdown.js** file without `$(document).ready`

Comment: If the `alert()` call is working it means that the file *is* available. The problem might be between jQuery and turbolinks. Try changing `$(document).ready` to `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', yourCallback)`